# Big spikes in Google App Engine caused by idle time between internal GAE calls

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scalability, latency

We have an API with Googe App Engine. The process does as follows. We have two calls to datastore with objetify and a call with urlfetch (to an external API).

In many of the request we see that the response takes too long because there are empty time spaces between the datastore call and the urlfetch call. Some times the empty time is after the calls, sometimes before and sometimes in between. We may have spikes of 10s.

Example when the idle time is between the calls:
[image: Example when the idle time is between the calls]

Example when the idle time is before the calls:
[image: Example when the idle time is before the call]

This is the current configuration:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>${appengine.web.application}</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<module>default</module>
<instance-class>F4_1G</instance-class>
<automatic-scaling>
<min-idle-instances>3</min-idle-instances>
<max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
<min-pending-latency>30ms</min-pending-latency>
<max-pending-latency>automatic</max-pending-latency>
</automatic-scaling>
<system-properties>
<property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This does not happens every time somebody makes a request to our API, only from time to time. Our average request time is 600ms. Also, we don't make any other operation in between the calls.

Is this idle time happening because GAE does not scale properly?

---

[EDIT]

I did new tests to try to understand why I'm getting this high latency. We did two tests, one with the smallest machine (F1) and the other with the biggest one (F4_1G). The code consist on 2 datastore calls and a urlfetch to an external API.

Results with F1 instance:
[image: Results with F1 instance]

Results with F4_1G instance:
[image: Results with F4_1G instance]

As you'll see there are some high latency requests in the machine F1 while in the other machine everything goes as expected. The high latency request has idle time between calls like in my first question. I assume that the F1 instance got out of memory because it's smaller and we are doing many requests. So I have 3 questions:

1) Any of the machines should generate these high latency. When an instance is overloaded, GAE should start a new instance or make use of idle instances. Is this correct or am I missing something???

2) Could the reason be that GAE does not scale correctly? (I hope not because then GAE would be a complete failure). Do we need to change the configuration?

3) I solved the problem by using the biggest machine. What should I do when a F4_1G machine gets this latency? There is no bigger machine.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "fact" that supposedly gae doesnt scale properly? how so?

Comment: @ZigMandel I don't know if GAE is scaling properly or not. I think that could be the problem but I don't know. That is why I'm asking. Any ideas why is this happening???

Comment: gae does scale properly. thats basically why gae exists.

Comment: @ZigMandel great, gae scales properly. Do you have any other idea why I'm having this problem?

Comment: no sorry i do not know. but i wanted to clear up the scaling thing because you initially stated it as a "fact" that gae doesnt scale well (now edited)

Comment: maybe related to the garbage collector?

Comment: Thank you. We will try to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Also we believe that it is not a memory problem because we saw that this problem appear even when a new instance has just started

Comment: @ZigMandel sorry to bother you but we did some tests and it seems that the problem is that GAE is not scaling properly. Please take a look at my answer below. Can somebody explain the behavior??

Comment: GAE *scales* properly, you are not using it properly is a more likely scenario. Even with your new tests you a still just **guessing** at why **your** code is not behaving as expected, I think your understanding/expectation is not inline with what want vs what you are doing. If a larger specification instance works then it is definitely a problem with your code/expectations of the lower spec configuration.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson it is odd because the code is the same in both instances.  Also, the code is very very simple. There are two calls to datastore and a call to urlfetch. Besides, if there is a problem with the code, then why only happens from time to time, shouldn't be happening always? How can you explain the idle time before the first datastore call? there isn't any operation.    What do you mean that my understanding/expectation is not inline what I'm doing?

Comment: Any idea? we changed the resident instance from 3 to 7 and we still have the same problem